# regex string between html <br>

Tags: regex, expression

I'am new to regular expression.
I'D like to extract all the string between html tag 
that contain a substring
For example , for the HTML below  :

```
 <span class='mouseOverHeader'>Test TEst</span>
 <div class='mouseOverData'>
 xxx cccc ccccc<br>qqq wwww wwww<br>qqq qqq MYSUBSTRING<br><br>
 <a id="email" style="cursor:pointer" onclick=">mmmmmm</a>
 </div>
```

I'd like to extract the string  "qqq qqq MYSUBSTRING"
because it contains the substring I am looking for "MYSUBSTRING"

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: don't test your regex against html or xml.

Comment: @AvinashRaj could you explain why ?

Comment: try `[^<>]*MYSUBSTRING[^<>]*`

Comment: is the html always well-formed?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to parse HTML is by building a tree (something similar to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) in Python, [HTML::Tree](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Tree.pm) in Perl)

The reason for this is that because of the nested nature of HTML's tags, as well as embedding other languages, Regex will often fail and/or produce a wrong output. I believe the way those modules are doing it is by building a tree via pushing and popping tags (read brackets `<>`) onto a stack and popping them out whenever they are closed (read `</>`)

If you however wish to stick with regex, try starting with this:

```
while($code =~ m/<br>(.+?)<br>/g)
{
 print "$1\n";
}
```

This regex will only match the first group, but the `while` loop will make it match until it hits a substring that does not have the pattern.
I would strongly recommend you to practice on some online visual Regex matcher, that highlights the groups as you type (try **RegExr**).